# Can we place a verb before a long subject (ten words) in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

I need to put the verb *(to develop)* in its proper place in the following passive-voice sentence:

> In that book were developed the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.

The proper order in English is subject–verb, which would be:

> In that book, the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties were developed.

But in this sentence, the subject and its modifying phrases contain ten words. If we use the order verb–subject (first option), then the sentence is easier to read.

Comment: You can do it.  Not ideal.

Comment: The first version is stiff and scary. The second version is reasonable, but the best I can see is *That book developed the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties*.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to discuss a sentence I feel is not totally felicitous. I'd prefer  'In this book, how the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties developed is discussed' or the idiomatic transferred usage of 'discuss':  'This book discusses  how the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties developed'.

Comment: @Edwin: there is a very important difference between developing an idea, and discussing the development of an idea. Einstein developed relativity. You might say that a physics textbook also develops relativity. But only a history of physics book would ***discuss*** the development of relativity.

Comment: @Peter So you're saying that the 'expound' sense of 'develop' is default here. In a seminal work, the 'cause something to grow or change into a more advanced, larger, or stronger form' [[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/develop)] is in play. Euclid, say. Or editions of some textbooks, most dictionaries. I'd prefer 'expound'.

Comment: I would say that the verb is currently in its proper place: (1) It presents familiar information, "that book", at the beginning and new information, "the basic ideas about ...", at the end, which is a fundamental principle of expository writing. (2) As you note, it doesn't start with ten words before it gets to the verb, which makes it hard to read. If you do want to simplify it, @Yosef Baskin's suggestion is excellent (but your wording makes it seem like you want to keep the sentence passive).

Answer (score 0):

Your first sentence displays [locative inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Locative_inversion), where fronting the prepositional phrase of location causes the subject and verb to invert:

> *In that book were developed the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.*

This would be the uninverted version:

> *The basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties were developed in that book.*

Note that your inversion, though awkward, works *because* you are using the passive voice (with its lack of a grammatical object); if you want to invert using the active voice (which you may wish to consider), you must use an intransitive verb:

> **Transitive active**: *Hooke developed the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties in that book.*
>   **Inverted**: **In that book developed Hooke the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.* (incorrect)
>
> **Intransitive active**: *The basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties emerged in that book.*
>   **Inverted**: *In that book emerged the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.*

I want to show you one more type of inversion that could serve your purposes. Here, the passive verb's auxiliary and participle are inverted:

> *Developed in that book were the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties.*

Now you have the passive voice, the long subject at the end, and a less awkward (albeit more formal) construction.

Answer (score -1):

In cases where an element is *heavy* (long), it may be postposed (moved to the end or near the end of the clause). There is a tendency or preference for a heavy constituent to appear late in the clause, especially where the constituent(s) over which it is moved are relatively light (CaGEL p1382-1384).

What makes this rather interesting is that if another element in the clause *In that book* were not preposed (moved to the left of its basic position), the postposing of the subject would be unacceptable:

> *Were developed the basic ideas about the cell and its biological properties in that book.

CaGEL calls this subject-dependent inversion where the subject may be postposed only if some other element - a locative in this case - is preposed. They also list some constraints on using this construction (CaGEL p1386):

> i The preposed phrase must not represent information that is less
>   familiar in the discourse than that represented by the postposed NP.
>
> ii Unless the preposed dependent is semantically locative, the
>   inversion requires an appropriate open proposition that is
>   discourse-old.
>
> iii The verb must not represent information that is new to the
>   discourse.

Condition one and two seem to have been met, but number three is questionable. Most of the examples given as acceptable have verbs that could easily be replaced with copula *be*, which is the most common verb used in these sorts of constructions (CaGEL p1398):

> i He opened the door and took a folded canvas bucket from behind
>   the seat.[Coiled on the floor lay a fifty-foot length of braided nylon
>   climbing rope.]
>
> ii Beneath the chin strap of the helmet sprouted black whiskers.
>
> iii On the manager’s desk sat a large manila envelope.
>
> iv [At odds with the mayor remain the residents of the condos,] who
>   are willing to fight a long battle over the additional taxes.

*Lay, sprouted, sat*, and *remain* do not really add much information, but in your example *developed* seems to add new information - it contrasts with other possible verbs like *discussed, debated, challenged*, etc.

Comment: You're misunderstanding CaGEL here. For readable exposition, you need to put familiar information at the beginning of a sentence and important new information at the end. The important new piece of information here is probably "the basic idea about the cell and its biological properties," while "that book" is familiar information. The word "developed" is unimportant information, and so is irrelevant to constraint (iii). See the article [*The Science of Scientific Writing*](https://www.americanscientist.org/blog/the-long-view/the-science-of-scientific-writing) from the *American Scientist*.

Comment: I don't see how _developed_ is unimportant information as it specifies the treatment of _the basic idea..._. It would seem to be highly important depending on one's interest in this book, be it acquiring a basic understanding, interest in new developments or historical progress in this area.

Comment: Maybe I should have said *less important*. But one of the main theses of the article *The Science of Scientific Writing* is that the most important new information should come at the end of the sentence, and for the OP's sentence, it seems very likely that "the basic idea about the cell and its biological properties" is the most important new information in that sentence. According to that article, then, this is what should go at the end of the sentence, and the fact that *developed* is somewhat less important new information should not prevent you from putting it there.